# Oracle 11 variable sensitivity of elapsed time to LINESIZE changes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I've read the documentation [tuning SQLPlus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#i1037682) regarding LINESIZE but I am struggling to work out why one set of oracle 11 servers seems to behave differently to another set of oracle 11 servers with respect to LINESIZE

Running the following queries gives me 'strange' elapsed time variation.

SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM <  140000;

1.1. sqlplus on sensitive servers

```
100   00:00:04.28 00:00:04.18 00:00:04.04
1000  00:00:06.48 00:00:06.37 00:00:06.32
10000 00:00:39.98 00:00:40.17 00:00:39.78
```

1.2. sqlplus on non-sensitive servers

```
100   00:00:04.90 00:00:04.93 00:00:04.77
1000  00:00:04.91 00:00:05.18 00:00:04.90
10000 00:00:05.79 00:00:05.54 00:00:05.74
```

SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM < 140000;

2.1. sqlplus on sensitive servers

```
100   00:00:06.65 00:00:07.53 00:00:06.88
1000  00:00:07.84 00:00:08.27 00:00:08.24
10000 00:00:40.71 00:00:41.54 00:00:40.60
```

2.2. sqlplus on non-sensitive servers

```
100   00:00:07.91 00:00:07.15 00:00:07.69
1000  00:00:05.64 00:00:05.59 00:00:05.52
10000 00:00:06.27 00:00:06.37 00:00:06.34
```

The only variable I changed in running these queries was the LINESIZE setting. I repeatedly ran the same query with LINESIZE set to 100, 1000, 10000.

My main question is: why is one set of servers seemingly more sensitive to changing LINESIZE than the other set. The sensitive servers range from 4s to 40s, the non-sensitive ones range only range from 4s to 7s.

What could explain this difference in 'sensititivity' ?

Looking at the 2.2 numbers, we see the variability induced by "LINESIZE too small", a larger LINESIZE results in a lower elapsed time (going from 100 to 1000).
But why is the same effect not visible in the 2.1 numbers.

Note:

- Identical sqlplus clients are used with identical settings reported
  by SHOW ALL.
- Oracle stats returned by autotrace are virtually identical (no order
  of magnitude variations)
- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit
  Production

Comment: Are you using exactly the same SQL*Plus client (the exact same binary)?  Or are you using a different executable on each server?  I'm guessing the latter so the issue is how quickly the client can paint the screen (and, potentially, the size of the native client window) and how quickly it can fetch the data.  A trace of the session might be interesting but I'm not sure that you'd want to spend too much time trying to tune how quickly a text app can paint the screen.

Comment: Yes, I am using exactly the same (same chksum) client executable on all sets of boxes.
    `cksum `which sqlplus``
    `262059320 11753 /xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx//xxx/sqlplus`

   `sqlplus -v`

    `SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production`

Comment: Sorry.  Are you saying there is a single client machine that connects to each of the servers?  Or are you saying that you are running SQL*Plus on each different server independently (though the same version of SQL*Plus)?

Comment: I am running this in multiple environments (various test environments) that are meant to be 'identical'.  There is a box where the sqlplus is run from, connected to a db server on another box.  I am running this in 'analogous' client-server configurations.  Imagine a given setup for production. Then this entire setup is duplicated for various test environments (performance test, user acceptance test, ... )

Comment: I did notice that the numbers for 'bytes sent/received via SQL*Net to client' reported by autotrace did not vary when I changed LINESIZE. I guess this means that the amount of data between sqlplus and the db server does not change with LINESIZE. Does this then mean that LINESIZE only affects what sqlplus does after it has received the data from the query.

Comment: I would expect it to be dominated by how quickly `SQL*Plus` can draw a bunch of text on the screen and how much text needs to be drawn.  That's  why this seems like a rather odd thing to be worried about-- very few people are concerned about how quickly a text based application can refresh data on a screen.  I've certainly never faced a situation where the bottleneck was SQL*Plus's ability to dump a heap of text to the screen.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right.  I crossed the sqlplus client over. So from ('bad' sqlplus -> 'bad' server,   'good' sqlplus -> 'good' server ) to ( 'bad' sqlplus -> 'good' server,  'good' sqlplus -> 'bad' server). The 'sensitivity' followed the 'sqlplus'.   Turns out that although the sqlplus executables are identical, the shared libs that they use aren't.  
Thanks a lot for your comments, it crystalised matters for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this irksome problem.

The version of the sqlplus client we're using is: SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

The setting that separated the 'sensitive' from the 'non-sensitive' sqlplus hosts was the `NLS_LANG` environment variable. 
On the non-sensitive ones the variable was not set and thus defaults to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`
On the sensitive ones the variable was set to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`

Once you know what to look for , the following links appear: 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/979446?tstart=0